# Problem with e-mail server

Tags: mysql, postfix, courier

I follow this tutorial  step by step and in the end

http://wiki.mediatemple.net/w/DV:Install_Postfix_on_Ubuntu#Configuring_TLS_and_SASL_authentication
 and i can make mi server work correctly

the imap and the pop3 never work on roundcube and squirrelmail , also i prube with a telnet.

Im new i don't have idea if the tutorial is right and yes i have a VE on mediatemple and i love it but i been all day and i can mak it work

this is the error i keep get it

> -ERR Temporary problem, please try again later

```
Dec 28 21:04:25 protectopymelegal imapd: LOGIN FAILED, user=hola@protectopymelegal.com, ip=[::ffff:127.0.0.1]

Dec 28 21:04:25 protectopymelegal imapd: authentication error: Connection refused



Dec 28 21:08:59 protectopymelegal imapd: Connection, ip=[::ffff:205.186.158.78]

Dec 28 21:08:59 protectopymelegal imapd: authdaemon: s_connect() failed: Connection refused

Dec 28 21:08:59 protectopymelegal imapd: [Hint: perhaps authdaemond is not running?]




Dec 28 20:52:18 protectopymelegal postfix/cleanup[12149]: warning: 0A1CF4834733: virtual_alias_maps map lookup problem for hola@protectopymelegal.com

Dec 28 20:52:54 protectopymelegal imapd: LOGIN FAILED, user=hola@protectopymelegal.com, ip=[::ffff:205.186.158.78]

Dec 28 20:55:03 protectopymelegal pop3d: LOGIN FAILED, user=hola@protectopymelegal.com, ip=[::ffff:127.0.0.1]

Dec 28 20:55:21 protectopymelegal postfix/cleanup[12149]: warning: 0F27C4834733: virtual_alias_maps map lookup problem
```

Comment: Do you have some informations in your logs ? Give us some errors logs to diagnose your problem, please !

Comment: Are you trying to send or receive emails, or both? Do you have any more errors?

Comment: i post the log entry from imap and that is the only error i can san mails i install mailx but i can authenticate to make a real test

Answer (score 0):

Your imap server can't connect to the authentication daemon. Is saslauthd running ?

Saslauthd only does the interface between your IMAP server and the backend that contains your users (mysql ?). You need to make sure that the connection between saslauthd and mysql works, that mysql contains your users, etc etc...

You should take a closer look at

```
testsaslauthd - test utility for the SASL authentication server
```